# Want to use IF statement with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have very simple code taking items from a **JSON** file and displaying them in a **DIV**. However, currently I am accessing each item based on its order in the array. I want to add an IF statement in addition to each item incase the order gets changed in the **JSON** file. Each item has its own id as well. For example, `data[0].itemName` could end up becoming `data[1].itemName` if the **JSON** file is altered.

```
(function() {

 'use strict';

 var url = 'path to json';

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

            $('#recipeIngredients').html(

            "<ul>" + 
                "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + '2 cups ' + (data._id == "1" ? data.itemName : " ") + "</li>" +
                "<li>" + data.itemName + "</li>" +
            "</ul>");

 });
```

})();

**JSON** is as follows:

```
var data = [ { "itemName" : "exampleItem1", "_id" : "1" }, { "itemName" : "exampleItem2", "_id" : "2" } ]
```

Comment: provide more information...what is your json looks like...

Comment: adding it to the top thanks

Comment: it's unclear what's preventing you from using said if statement

Comment: when i try to put an if statement in the <li>  before data[5].itemName for example, it doesnt work

Comment: show your attempt and explain what do you mean as "it doesn't work"

Comment: you're inside of a string concatenation, you can assign to a temp variable or something before this code or use ?: operator

Comment: i added it above. i want to ensure the item has the correct id (that field is also in the json file for each of the items as well)

Comment: @aw04 can you show me an example? something like this? <li>" + '2 cups ' +  if (data_id == "2") ? data[4].itemName + "</li>"

Comment: actually filter may be a better solution, just keep in mind it returns an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I think you need to read up on the ternary operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the syntax in your last comment is wrong

Comment: Instead of `if (data_id == "2") { data.itemName }` try `data[data_id - 1].itemName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this example

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "itemName": "exampleItem1"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "itemName": "exampleItem2"
}];
var ul = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ul += "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
    "<li>" + '2 cups ' +
    (data[i].id == "2" ? data[i].itemName : " ") +
    "</li>" +
    "<li>" + data[i].itemName + "</li>";

}
ul += "</ul>";
document.body.innerHTML = ul;
```

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "itemName": "exampleItem1"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "itemName": "exampleItem2"
}];
var ul = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ul += "<li>" + '1/2 tsp salt' + "</li>" +
    "<li>" + '2 cups ';
//if statement should like this
if(data[i].id == "2") ul += data[i].itemName;
//add else if you want
else ul += "_ _ _";

  ul += "</li>" +
    "<li>" + data[i].itemName + "</li>";

}
ul += "</ul>";
document.body.innerHTML = ul;
```

Comment: this works but Im not trying to use a loop. Just want to do an if statement to see whether the id is correct for the item

Comment: So this should do the task `+ (data.id == "2" ? data.itemName : " ") +`

Comment: still cant get it to output the item. ill post my updated (full code) above

Comment: if i add the [0] infront of data._id like data[0]_id it works but that still would still cause problems if the json data is altered (the order) correct?

Comment: you mean this `data[0]._id` not `data[0]_id || data._id`

Comment: every thing will work with the same `data` structure with new values or keys whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Surely your data structure should include the quantity (and unit of measure) for each recipe item? A system that can only display recipes that require 2 cups of a particular ingredient would be very inflexible!

Assuming you control the content of the JSON structure, something like the below would work much better:

```js
var data = [{"id": "1", "itemName": "salt", "itemQty": "1/2 tsp"},
            {"id": "2", "itemName": "flour", "itemQty": "2 cups"},
            {"id": "3", "itemName": "Eggs", "itemQty": "2"}];

document.write("<ul>");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    document.write("<li>" + data[i].itemQty + " " + data[i].itemName);
}
document.write("<ul>");
```

Then your UI code is simply outputting the data given to it - no embedded logic required.